# If/then only when values after second line

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, firewall

I'm trying to add IP addresses blacklisted by the PF firewall to a log so we have a record of them over time, preferably with the date/time they were added.

The following command shows the IP addresses I'd like to capture:

```
% pfctl -t bruteforce -T show
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
   1.2.3.4
   2.3.4.5
```

But the first two lines (No ALTQ support in kernel, ALTQ related functions disabled) need to be stripped out, and I'm having no luck with awk, sed, or tail doing that. I'd think the following might work, but no joy:

```
% pfctl -t bruteforce -T show | sed 1,2d
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
```

And I'm also wondering then how best to weave this into an if/then statement so that only when there are results (I.e. any IP addresses), this is then written to the log, preferably with the date/time they were added.

Apologies for being such a greenhorn with this -- any ideas or help is much appreciated.

Dan

Comment: Are you sure about that `sed 1,2d` example? It should work, and produce not what you posted, but the first two lines deleted, showing only IP addresses. Please double-check.

Comment: is this all in a linux/unix environment, or is windows involved (anywhere), if so add `| dos2unix - | sed ...` . GOod luck.

Comment: @janos, yes I'm sure, this puzzled me, too! I'm on OS X. Don't think it's a dos2unix issue...but I can test that this is indeed the case.

Comment: @Dan works fine for me on OS X too. This is simple enough, should work the same way on both BSD and GNU. Your output really looks as if you did `sed -n 1,2p`, the opposite of `sed 1,2d`

Comment: I guess the 2 lines he wants to get rid off are actually printed onto stderr. Test this: `pfctl -t bruteforce -T show 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try piping the output into `awk` and specifying that you only want line numbers greater than '2' 'NR>2':

```
pfctl -t bruteforce -T show | awk 'NR>2'
```

To put that into a script one might:

```
#!/bin/sh

logfile="logfile.txt"

pass=0

for i in $( pfctl -t bruteforce -T show | awk 'NR>2' )
do   # only log the date once
     [ "$pass" -eq 0 ] && { date >> "$logfile" ; pass=1 ; }
     # log the ip addresses to "$logfile" one at a time
     printf "$i\n" >> "$logfile"
done
```

Comment: thanks for this, but it's not producing results, either. It outputs the same first two lines but not the IPs that follow. Puzzling for sure! I'm on OS X but don't think there's anything special about that here.

Comment: Perhaps some of pfctl's diagnostic messages are written to stderr. Can you successfully redirect all of the output of  'pfctl -t bruteforce -T show > somefile'? If not, then try with  'pfctl -t bruteforce -T show 2>somefile' to catch any message that might be printed to stderr.

Comment: I think you're onto something. Interestingly enough, 'pfctl -t bruteforce -T show > /tmp/pf.out' shows the IP addresses and not the first two lines. No sed, no awk, nothing.

Comment: And 'pfctl -t bruteforce -T show 2> /tmp/out' shows the first two lines and not the IP addresses.

Comment: So your script above works perfectly, then, without the awk. Thanks for your help, marking this as answered.

Comment: Y'know, most tools have options to simply suppress the information that gets printed to stderr. You might have another look at the `pfctl` man page. If you don't want to see lines though and can't just turn them off, redirect to `/dev/null` not some real file you'll create like `/tmp/out`.